# prepare data for CNTK LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, lstm

Hi I want to prepare my data, which will be then used to learn LSTM network.

I use pandas and numpy arrays.

I have csv file which i read like

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",....)
```

That csv file contains values of wind direction and hour of day and some other values...

Hour of day is represented as integer from 0 to 24. I need it to be represented by values of sinus and cosinus.

Wind direction is represented as one or two characters like: NW, N, SE, etc..
(NW - northwest, N - north, ... etc) - I need it to be represented by values of sinus and cosinus as well.

I am a newbie in pandas, python and everything mentioned here...

Thak you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
Please provide examples of your input, your expected output, and your coding attempts so far..

Comment: Thank you for your kindness :) I already figured it out.. I will write here an answer and close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out...

I will just create two values from one. "Time" will be represented by two values, one sinus and other cosinus and they will feed my LSTM...

I will do the same with "wind direction"..

(i will do this manually with external script and then read csv with pandas...)